# I need help on how to hack into a scammer computer via IP/DNS

Tags: passwords, windows, penetration-test, attacks

I really need your help in this one. Today I got scammed by a "trader" for 100$, but I managed to get his IP, reverse DNS and Hostname but I am unskilled in hacking. I need help here, I just want to hack into his PC and prevent future frauds to other people, and of course get some satisfaction because I got lied to. I'm using win 8.1, and I will do everything possible to get to him, but again I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We do not teach hacking here.

Comment: Hacking is a crime in almost any country in the world, and all countries in the western world, i suggest staying away from that path and go with logs/screenshots and ofcourse those details to the nearest police departement

Comment: Committing a crime is not a valid response to a crime.  Report him to the authorities and hand off the information you have gathered (which thus far seems like it was probably legally acquired, though I am not a lawyer).

Comment: I agree with @Lighty, call law enforcement and leave it.

Comment: Fraud happens occasionally. Buy a boxing bag or something. For all you know, the trader works for the Russian mafia or a Mexican cartel. Best to just move on.

Comment: Boxing is certainly the way to go. Also you should look into stress managements techniques and educate yourself in how not to become a victim in the cyber scams...

Answer (score 5):

Hacking is a serious crime, and gets you in even a more of a problem.

It seems you have some details, try to gather logs, screenshots etc. and get to the nearest police station and report the crime.

Committing a crime in answer to a crime is **NOT** a solution.