# Is there any way to hack the password of my neighbour WPA-PSK and WEP connection

Tags: password-management, wifi, wireless, wpa2, wep

Is there any way to hack the password of my neighbour WPA-PSK and WEP connection of WI-FI without using a keylogger.

I tried a lots of softwares and efforts but unsuccessful. Can any one suggest. I want to try to hack only for educational purpose.

Comment: Why do we keep getting these [questions](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/70660/30521)?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have permission, breaking into someone else's network is illegal regardless of why you're doing so.  If you really want to learn about the security vulnerabilities of WPA-PSK and WEP, I recommend setting up your own AP and practice breaking into it.